# VS2010 options keep changing automatically (statement completion)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I always have to go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > General and re-enable the statement completion options.

Why do they keep getting disabled?

Comment: Do you have Resharper installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resharper version 5.something that was doing it. The latest update fixed it though.